# Java how to change color on g.drawString

Tags: java

I am trying to make the string currentTask in text red. However, it is white. I tried changing to red between like this, without any progress.

`g.drawString("Task: " + g.setColor(Color.red) + currentTask, 13, 60);`

```
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.drawString("Task: " + currentTask, 13, 60);
```

Comment: That code wouldn't compile: `setColor` is a void method. OTOH where you set the color to white (you say you want red) *would* compile. So change the color

Comment: Task can not be in red. Must be in white.

Comment: Well - set it to red for the bits that need to be in red! And you're going to *have* to call `drawString` again to do that of course

Comment: Instead of doing it all on your own you could use a component that supports HTML (e.g. `JLabel`) which would then allow you to use markup like `<html>Task: <font color="red">currentTask</font></html>" (you'd need to add the actual value for current task, of course, as well as escape the double quotes in the Java string).

Comment: Btw, `g.drawString("Task: " + g.setColor(Color.red) + currentTask, 13, 60); ` indicates you have a misconception of how Java evaluates that code and you might need to reiterate on that. Basically it _first_ builds the string `"Task: ..."` and _even if_ `g.setColor()` would return something that return value would be converted to a string using `toString()` and be part of the string parameter and _only after that is done_ will `g.drawString(...)` be called with the parameters already constructed. So on any case `g.setColor(...)` would be executed before `g.drawString(...)`.

Comment: *Java how to change color on g.drawString* - you don't. The drawString() method simply paints the text specified. It is a two step process: 1)  You change the color of the Graphics object 2) You invoke the drawString(...) method using that Graphics object. Repeats steps 1-2 as necessary for any text you want to paint in different colors.

Answer (score 2):

There are two `drawString` methods that accept an `AttributedCharacterIterator`. This is returned by `AttributedString.getIterator()`, so first such need to be created and configured.

Here a naïve solution:

```
var text = new AttributedString("Task: Test");
text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.WHITE, 0, 6);
text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.RED, 6, 10);

g.drawString(text.getIterator(), x, y);
```

<sup>obviously this must be expanded to concatenate `currentTask` instead of using the literal "Test" and have the respective indices calculated to be used in `addAttribute`</sup>

---

To do it without `AttributedString`, that is, setting the color of `Graphics`, you would have to do something like:

```
private static final LABEL = "Task: ";
...
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.drawString(LABEL, x, y);
var delta = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(LABEL);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawString(currentTask, x+delta, y);
```